# Python email messages not threading in Outlook. Possible header issue? Custom format or line length a possible solution?

Tags: python, outlook, email-headers

An email comes in with the following header from an @outlook.com address

```
Message-ID:
 <DM5PR1101MB2074A897F300D11D32C71B75EC049@DM5PR1101MB2074.namprd11.prod.outlook.com>
```

To respond with Python I put that message identifier in the `In-Reply-To` header

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['In-Reply-To'] = '<DM5PR1101MB2074A897F300D11D32C71B75EC049@DM5PR1101MB2074.namprd11.prod.outlook.com>'
```

However, when I print this message the header appears as follows:

```
In-Reply-To: =?utf-8?q?=3CDM5PR1101MB2074A897F300D11D32C71B75EC049=40DM5PR11?=
 =?utf-8?q?01MB2074=2Enamprd11=2Eprod=2Eoutlook=2Ecom=3E?=
```

And when it arrives in Outlook it's not put in the same conversation thread as the original message.

Does anyone know why this may be happening and/or know of any work-around?

I suspect that this is happening because Python is trying to split the header across multiple lines since this header is above the RFC-specified line length and when it splits across multiple lines it starts each line with `'?utf-8?q` and converts the `<` character to `?=3C`, etc... Whereas Outlook is expecting the header to be of the format

```
In-Reply-To': 
 <DM5PR1101MB2074A897F300D11D32C71B75EC049@DM5PR1101MB2074.namprd11.prod.outlook.com>'
```

Perhaps if someone knows how to force the header to be in this format that would suffice as a work-around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried using the `add_header` method instead?

Comment: just tried it, same result

Comment: It seems you need to choose another library for that.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem with protonmail

Can solve by specifying max_header_length in policy

https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.policy.html#email.policy.Policy.max_line_length

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.policy import EmailPolicy

EmailMessage(
    policy=EmailPolicy(max_line_length=None)
)
```

Comment: thanks Rich, however I had to use `EmailMessage(policy=EmailPolicy(max_line_length=float("inf")))` which solved the line breaking but the threading is still not working

Comment: what do you get when you do str(the_email_message)